# Как в vscode перетаскивать текст в скобки (картинки внутри)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Когда выделяешь текст и перетаскиваешь мышкой, то вверх или ниже перетаскивается, а вставить например в console.log(сюда) не хочет. Вертикальные точки это перемещение куда вставить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а у меня нормально перетаскивается. Когда появились эта точки внутри скобок надо отпускать и текст переместится в скобки

Comment: хз, и вправду на ноуте вставляется, на pс  не хочет. попробую может переустановить

Comment: все решил, одно из расширений мешало

Comment: стоит написать ответ: какое именно расширение мешало и как решил в итоге

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто по очереди удалял расширения и нашел(правда не смогу сказать какое, потому что не запомнил после какого) и заработало.

Comment: вся проблема из-за включенной quokka c плагином "bracket pair colorizer 2"